# Why can't I see WM_VSCROLL messages in my wndproc when using WS_VSCROLL style?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, message

I'm creating a message loop in plain C that interfaces to my Harbour-based project. So far, everything works just fine, except for scrollbars in dialogs which have the `WS_VSCROLL` style. My message loop doesn't seem to see the `WM_VSCROLL` message, but it does see the `WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN` message with the `HTVSCROLL` value in `Msg.wParam`. Anybody have any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: Is this a dialog box or a regular window?  I don't think all messages get handed off to a dialog proc.